# How and when did astrology become a defining aspect of Hinduism?

Tags: history, rituals, astrology

Many aspects of Hindu rituals are closely tied with astrology, star gazing and charts. How and when did this start to happen?

Comment: Hello and welcome to http://hinduism.stackexchange.com, your question sounds bit vague and also unclear, can you precisely define of what you are looking for by providing more details in your question?

Comment: This I think was mentioned in Vedas and Vedas were not written by us. So, we can't say the time. but still, honestly, I am not sure.

Comment: but, you are actually right Mr_Green :) Just that the present form of astrology is not present in the vedas

Answer (score 4):

Astrology was a defining aspect since the beginning of Hinduism. The core of Hinduism is the Vedas and in one way, the core of the Vedas are the rituals and *yajnas* (sacrifices). The Vedas define particular moments, planetary positions etc. when the rituals or yajna should be started. Hence, since the prehistoric times *rishis* (sages) and *munis* started star gazing.

The thing is, to understand the Veda and its *mantras* properly and to understand the time table and planetary positions properly, knowledge of certain other things like grammar, meter (to chant the mantras), astronomy (to know the time of ritual), etc. are also required. Hence, these (six in number) are known as the limb of the Vedas (*Vedanga*):

> तत्रापरा रुग्वेदो यजुर्वेदः सामवेदोऽथर्ववेदः
>     शिक्षा कल्पो व्याकरणं निरुक्तं छन्दो ज्योतिषमिति |
>     अथ परा यया तदक्षरमधिगम्यते  [Mundak. Up. - 1.1.5]
>
> **Meaning**
>   Of these (Knowledge), Rig Veda, Yajur Veda, Sam Veda, Atharv Veda,
>   Sikhsa (phonetics), kalpa (ritual), vyakaran (grammar), nirukta (word
>   definitions), chanda (meter), jyotisha (astrology) are lower. And the
>   higher than these is the knowledge through which the imperishable is
>   attained.

So astronomy is as old as the Vedas, but later on sages and scholars like Parashara, Garga, Varah Mihir, etc. formulated more precise rules and helped gain it today's form which are used to calculate birth charts, forecast future, etc.

I don't know whether it count's as a proper reference, but in the Shri Krishna serial of Ramananda Sagar I had heard that Garga was the sage who first created the planetary chart system (in the episode where he names Krishna). The Vishnu Puran also states Garga as the ancient rishi who learned *jyotishi* from Sesha (*Ananta Naga*):

> *yamārādhya purāṇarvirgagoṃ jyortīṣi tattvataḥ
>
>     jñātavānsakalaṃ caiva nimittapaṭhitaṃ phalam*  [VP - 2.5.26]
>
> **Meaning**
>   Worshipping him (Sesha), the ancient *rishi* Garga obtained the complete knowledge of *jyotishi* (astrology) and the auspicious and inauspicious effects of planetary positions.